# ANSI C compliant or C++ cross-platform GUI library?

Tags: qt, user-interface, gtk, cross-platform

I'm searching for a simple library for creating GUI that can have:

1. a portable codebase across different compilers and OS
2. can be easily extended to a new platform if that platform it's not natively supported
3. are **real** library and not just a collection of `#define`, tools and other un-portable and non-standard things.

So far the "best" match is QT that is just the opposite of each one of this 3 points, especially the 3rd one (moc compiler and #defines ... ).

I also do not need data structures and 10000 extra functions, i just need to code a portable GUI, hipotetically i don't even need a signal slot library included because I can handle signals with third part libraries.

If there is no such lib available can you point me to a resource where I can learn about the OS specific basics about Widgets and Windows ?

Comment: Qt is C++ not C, as far as I know.

Comment: @dualed i forgot to add the C++ to the question ...

Comment: I am not sure how you came to the conclusion that Qt is the opposite of the 3 points you listed. Qt is portable across compilers and Os, it is constantly being extended to new platforms (it's currently being extended to iOS and it's been on Android for a while), and it's anything but "just a collection of #define".

Comment: @Fred i don't care about on how many platforms it's being ported, it's not my point. Qt is not portable mainly because of many hardcoded #define and the requirement of the moc compiler during the build process. Qt not only need to be ported, their tools also need to be rewritten for a specific platform in order to support a normal workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I never used it, but I would suggest looking into [IUP](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/)

From what I read this would fit the bill quite well. The project is also quite active. Though it is probably not too pretty.

Comment: with "not too pretty" you mean that does not offer too many widgets ?

Comment: @user1797612 I mean optically pleasing. It uses native controls and lets face it, some platforms have a really ugly set of standard controls. But it all depends on what you need.